# How do I stop my background images from overlapping on top of each other

Tags: html, css, background

I want the background images to appear side by side (Equally Sized), with no spaces between them. My code does this, but the images overlap a bit on top of each other, thereby making it not span 100% of the container.

I set the background-size to 25% 100%;, but the images overlap a bit, I don't want them to overlap. I want them to equally sized and appear side by side, with no spacing between them.

```css
    .education {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.8), rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.5)),
        url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random1)  no-repeat fixed, url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random2) no-repeat fixed, url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random3) no-repeat fixed, url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random4) no-repeat fixed;
        background-size: 25% 100%;
        background-position: 0% 0%, 25% 0%, 50% 0%, 75% 0%;
    }
```

```html
<section id="education" class="education">
                <div class="content-wrap">
                <h2>Education</h2>https://jsfiddle.net/Temitope/61pz03hy/5/#run
    
                <!-- School details: copy this whole block to add more schools. -->
                <h3>Andela - Lagos, Nigeria</h3>
                <p>Mobile Web Specialist Certificate, 2019</p>
                <p>Five Months Learning Program. </p>
    
                <h3>University Of  Lagos - Akoka, Lagos</h3>
                <p>Bachelor of Science, 2013-2017</p>
                <p>Major in Economics and International Trade.</p>
    
                <h3>Kith and Kin International College - Ikorodu, Lagos</h3>
                <p>West African Exam Council Certificate, 2009-2013</p>
                <p> Major in Commerce.</p>
              </div>
            </section>
```

I want the background images to appear side by side (Equally Sized), with no spaces between them. I also want the images to resize themselves based on the device width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the background-position to: 0% 0%, 33.333% 0%, 66.667% 0%, 100% 0%;. My Horizontal Values were wrong, they only spaned up to 75% of the container.

```css
.education {
     background: linear-gradient(rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.8), rgba(141, 153, 174, 0.5)),
     url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random1)  no-repeat fixed, url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random2) no-repeat fixed, url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random3) no-repeat fixed, url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?random4) no-repeat fixed;
     background-size: 25% 100%;
     background-position:  0% 0%, 33.333% 0%, 66.667% 0%, 100% 0%;;
 }
```

```html
<section id="education" class="education">
            <div class="content-wrap">
            <h2>Education</h2>

            <!-- School details: copy this whole block to add more schools. -->
            <h3>Andela - Lagos, Nigeria</h3>
            <p>Mobile Web Specialist Certificate, 2019</p>
            <p>Five Months Learning Program. </p>

            <h3>University Of  Lagos - Akoka, Lagos</h3>
            <p>Bachelor of Science, 2013-2017</p>
            <p>Major in Economics and International Trade.</p>

            <h3>Kith and Kin International College - Ikorodu, Lagos</h3>
            <p>West African Exam Council Certificate, 2009-2013</p>
            <p> Major in Commerce.</p>
          </div>
        </section>
```